# Symfony 2 computer hungs when I make any request

Tags: php, symfony

Excuse me for my English.

I have 3 classes: **User**, **Category** and **Service**.

When I do even a simple query to the database for **Service**, for example **findAll()**, my computer hangs... At the same time, the query for **Category** and **User** are good.

Thank you for your help!

User.php

```
namespace General\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your type.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
 * @Assert\Length(
 *     min=3,
 *     max="255",
 *     minMessage="The type is too short.",
 *     maxMessage="The type is too long.",
 *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
 * )
 */
protected $type;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set type
 *
 * @param string $type
 * @return User
 */
public function setType($type)
{
    $this->type = $type;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get type
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getType()
{
    return $this->type;
}
}
```

Category.php

```
namespace General\AnnuaireBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="General\AnnuaireBundle\Entity\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="statut", type="boolean")
 */
private $statut;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
 */
private $createdAt;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\General\AnnuaireBundle\Entity\Service", mappedBy="categories")
 */
private $services;


/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct() {
   $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
   $this->services = new ArrayCollection();
}


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Category
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param string $description
 * @return Category
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * Set statut
 *
 * @param boolean $statut
 * @return Category
 */
public function setStatut($statut)
{
    $this->statut = $statut;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get statut
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getStatut()
{
    return $this->statut;
}

/**
* @ORM\PrePersist()
*/
public function setCreatedAt($createdAt = null) {
    $this->createdAt = null === $createdAt ? new \DateTime() : $createdAt;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get createdAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getCreatedAt()
{
    return $this->createdAt;
}

/**
 * Add services
 *
 * @param \General\AnnuaireBundle\Entity\Service $services
 * @return Category
 */
public function addService(\General\AnnuaireBundle\Entity\Service $services)
{
    $this->services[] = $services;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove services
 *
 * @param \General\AnnuaireBundle\Entity\Service $services
 */
public function removeService(\General\AnnuaireBundle\Entity\Service $services)
{
    $this->services->removeElement($services);
}

/**
 * Get services
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getServices()
{
    return $this->services;
}
}
```

Service.php

```
namespace General\AnnuaireBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Service
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="General\AnnuaireBundle\Entity\ServiceRepository")
 */
class Service
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="statut", type="boolean")
 */
private $statut;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
 */
private $createdAt;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\General\AnnuaireBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="services")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $categories;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\General\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 */
private $users;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct() {
   $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Service
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param string $description
 * @return Service
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * Set statut
 *
 * @param boolean $statut
 * @return Service
 */
public function setStatut($statut)
{
    $this->statut = $statut;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get statut
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getStatut()
{
    return $this->statut;
}

/**
 * Set createdAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $createdAt
 * @return Service
 */
public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
{
    $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get createdAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getCreatedAt()
{
    return $this->createdAt;
}

/**
 * Set categories
 *
 * @param \General\AnnuaireBundle\Entity\Category $categories
 * @return Service
 */
public function setCategories(\General\AnnuaireBundle\Entity\Category $categories = null)
{
    $this->categories = $categories;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get categories
 *
 * @return \General\AnnuaireBundle\Entity\Category 
 */
public function getCategories()
{
    return $this->categories;
}

/**
 * Set users
 *
 * @param \General\UserBundle\Entity\User $users
 * @return Service
 */
public function setUsers(\General\UserBundle\Entity\User $users = null)
{
    $this->users = $users;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get users
 *
 * @return \General\UserBundle\Entity\User 
 */
public function getUsers()
{
    return $this->users;
}
}
```

Controller.php

```
public function showServicesAction() 
{        
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
$services = $em->getRepository('GeneralAnnuaireBundle:Service')->findAll();

return $this->render('GeneralAnnuaireBundle:General:list_services.html.twig',
                     array('services'=>$services,
                         )
);
}
```

If I modified my function as:

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
$user_id = $user->getId();
// var_dump($user_id);       ALL IS RIGHT

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 

$services = $em->getRepository('GeneralAnnuaireBundle:Service')->findAll();

// var_dump($user_id);     ALL IS RIGHT

// IF:  var_dump($services[0]);      COMPUTER HUNGS 

// IF:  echo count($services);        RESPONSE RIGHT

// IF:  
return $this->render('GeneralAnnuaireBundle:General:list_services.html.twig',
                         array('services'=>$services, ));
                               // SCREEN WHITE
```

Comment: there can be thousand reasons why a computer hangs. So the question is: Where does it hang with? CPU goes up for a specific process? If so, which one?

Comment: Sounds like an endless loop or a resource problem in the entity manager. is CPU going up when this hangs? And does `var_dump($services);` still work?

Comment: Thank you for your hint))) excuse me I'm zero in English

Comment: It's all fine, we go step by step.

Comment: I close this post. Actualy, when I loop the oject in *.twig **{% for service in services %}** all is right. But problem with **dump()** in PHP and **{{dump()}}** in HTML are still there. Thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print object in browser it get hanged because symphony object contains lots of info. suppose if you  have relation with other tables it will have current tables info as well as other related tables info (Schema, Data, Relationship etc.) as well so it might 99% chance to hanged the browser. Better to print "echo  count($services)" to check object exists or not.

Comment: You are right. I made as you said and browser showed me the response 5. It's right. But how I could get the datas if it hungs? Even I don't print object and render *.twig it hungs too... What i have do for solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Iren I have seen you are again  doing same thing in twig file. if you want to list the data into  twig you can simply do following  {% for service in services %} {{service.name }} <br/> {{service.description}} <br/> {{service.statut}}     {%end foreach %}

Answer (score 0):

Try Debug::dump($service) or any variable - you will be able to see the objects (without the proxy)